# The sequence of tenses

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> Ali was enjoying his weekend at the sports center in Manama. He was
> playing in a local pool championship. Ali **1 had played/had been
> playing** well for half an hour and **2 won/had won three** of the
> first five games. He put down the glass he **3 was drinking/had been
> drinking** from and was getting ready to pot the black to win the
> final game when his false teeth dropped out.

My take on it:
1 - both are possible
2 - both are possible
3 - not sure

Comment: This seems like a homework question, which isn't something we do here. Also, have you searched already for the differences among these tenses? What do you already know and what about these choices confuses you?

Comment: 2 and 3 are confusing. Especially 3. If it's "was drinking" then it's not logical. Is it OK to interrupt an action in the Past Continuous? "I put down the glass from which I was drinking". ???